# Can't mount secret to volume in /etc

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I have a K8s deployment that mounts a secret into `/etc/google-cloud-account` containing the Google auth JSON file to use from the application. When I try to run the deployment, I get the following error from my pod:

```
1m  1m  1   kubelet, gke-development-cluster-default-pool-17f531d7-sj4x spec.containers{api}    Normal  Created     Created container with docker id 36b85ec8415a; Security:[seccomp=unconfined]
1m  1m  1   kubelet, gke-development-cluster-default-pool-17f531d7-sj4x spec.containers{api}    Warning Failed      Failed to start container with docker id 36b85ec8415a with error: Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 2 desc = "oci runtime error: could not synchronise with container process: mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay/b4aa81194f72ccb54d88680e766a921ea26f7a4df0f4b32d6030123896b2b203/merged/etc/google-cloud-account: read-only file system"
1m  1m  1   kubelet, gke-development-cluster-default-pool-17f531d7-sj4x             Warning FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "api" with RunContainerError: "runContainer: Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 2 desc = \"oci runtime error: could not synchronise with container process: mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay/b4aa81194f72ccb54d88680e766a921ea26f7a4df0f4b32d6030123896b2b203/merged/etc/google-cloud-account: read-only file system\""

2m  13s 11  kubelet, gke-development-cluster-default-pool-17f531d7-sj4x spec.containers{api}    Warning BackOff     Back-off restarting failed docker container
```

The deployment in question looks like:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  # ...
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.api.replicaCount }}
  template:
    # ...
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Values.api.name }}
          # ...
          volumeMounts:
            - name: google-cloud-account
              mountPath: /etc/google-cloud-account
      volumes:
        - name: google-cloud-account
          secret:
            secretName: {{ template "fullname" . }}
            items:
              - key: google-cloud-credentials
                path: credentials.json
```

I don't know how `/etc` in the container would be a read only file system and don't know how to change that.

Comment: just try mounting it somewhere else. 
GKE uses CoreOS under the hood I'm pretty sure; it's a read only FS, so you should mount under something like /usr/local/ which should be R/W

Comment: @MrE see my answer below. It was related to another volume mount.

Comment: It might be nice to edit the question to actually include the problematic part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out the error was caused by another volume mount. I left it out of the end code, but my deployment looked more like the following:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  # ...
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.api.replicaCount }}
  template:
    # ...
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Values.api.name }}
          # ...
          volumeMounts:
            - name: google-cloud-account
              mountPath: /etc/google-cloud-account
            - name: odbc
              mountPath: /etc
      volumes:
        - name: google-cloud-account
          secret:
            secretName: {{ template "fullname" . }}
            items:
              - key: google-cloud-credentials
                path: credentials.json
        - name: odbc
          configMap:
            name: {{ template "fullname" . }}
            items:
              - key: odbc.ini
                path: odbc.ini
```

Mounting `odbc` took over the entire `/etc` directory. To fix it, I changed the `odbc` `volumeMount` to:

```
- name: odbc
  mountPath: /etc/odbc.ini
  subPath: odbc.ini
```

Which left everything else in `/etc` intact.

Comment: This is also relevant for things like dropping a single config file in an application directory that already has files

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to [Dave Long's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44557294/1845976) are [projected volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#projected):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  # ...
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.api.replicaCount }}
  template:
    # ...
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Values.api.name }}
          # ...
          volumeMounts:
            - name etc
              mountPath: /etc
            - name: google-cloud-account
              mountPath: /etc/google-cloud-account
            - name: odbc
              mountPath: /etc
      volumes:
        - name: config
          projected:
            sources:
            - secret:
                name: {{ template "fullname" . }}
                items:
                  - key: google-cloud-credentials
                    path: google-cloud-account/credentials.json
            - configMap:
                name: {{ template "fullname" . }}
                items:
                  - key: odbc.ini
                    path: odbc.ini
```